# Trigger jquery based on model events

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im aware there are many questions on SO about notifications, but I havent come across any that touch on triggering jquery to display notifications based on model events. I have notifications wrapped in a div with display set to none and would like to access jquery from the model to show them.

With 30+ different types of notifications, having this code (checks for whether a user should be prompted with a notification) in a controller's create.js.erb file is messy; using a callback would be highly preferred.

Please dont respond with the jquery show/hide methods as that's not what I'm asking. Any input would be greatly appreciated (well, any input other than explaining jquery's hide/show methods). Here is the callback:

```
  after_create :hundredrep

  def hundredrep
    unless Badge.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :name => "hundredrep", :category => "3").any?
        if current_user.reputation > 100 
            current_user.badges.create(:name =>"hundredrep", :category = "3")
        end
    end
  end
```

And the jquery I would like to be called on the above callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".browser_notice").slideDown(500);
});
```

Comment: Please format your question decently, this is very hard to read.

Comment: `Please dont respond with the jquery show/hide methods as that's not what I'm asking.` sort of contradicts `Any input would be greatly appreciated.`

Comment: Are you saying you want the model to notify JS on a `before_save` or similar callback? This totally breaks the MVC convention, there's no reason why the model should be aware of the UI at all. If you can give a more specific example of what you want to accomplish maybe I can help you think of a better way.

Comment: Yes, there must be some way to access the UI based on events in the database. In my specific case, I have a reputation system which notifies users when their 'points' attribute reaches certain milestones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push data from the server to the client you'll have to use one of these techniques :

- periodically send XHR calls to the server to fetch updates (technically speaking not a push)
- open a persistent connection with the server so that you the server can write data to the stream whenever needed (HTTP streaming / firehose API)
- send an XHR request that the server will let open until data push is required (HTTP long polling)

Depending on the level of reactivity you need (what is "realtime" : 1 second, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 1 minutes ?) the first approach is the simplest one. For HTTP streaming or long-polling you'll have to adopt the [Comet approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) / an event-driven IO server  such as Goliath, NodeJS, Tornado, etc.. You may also have a look to plug-and-play APIs such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com/).

To ensure DRYability use model callbacks or model observers to push events to Comet, to a table in your database, to Pusher or whatever solution fitting your needs.

Comment: Can you please provide some guidance on how I could implement the above notification with an XHR call in rails?